# How to get random array element onclick of a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a java script array with large number of elements inside it, on click of a button I want to display the any random array element on screen, for which I have used `Math.random` function, but not sure why it is not working.
here is my code below.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="getquotes" value="Quotes" onclick="Loadquotes();">Quotes</button>
    <p id="quoteshere" ></p>
    <script>
      var Loadquotes= function(){
        var quotes = new Array('Stack1','Stack2','Stack16','Stack17','Stack13','Stack14','Stack15','Stack6','Stack7','Stack8','Stack9','Stack10');
        var i;

        for (i=0;i<quotes.length;i++){
          var newquotes = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
          document.getElementById('quoteshere').value=newquotes;
        }
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `quotes.length` will be one more than the total number of items. Maybe try `quotes.length - 1`? - Also, `.value` isn't a valid property of a paragraph element, and even if it was, the for loop would just override the value multiple times.

Comment: @evolutionxbox tried it..but still not working

Answer (score 2):

`quoteshere` is `P` Tag `value` function won't work use `innerText` or `innerHTML` instead please find below snippet

```js
var Loadquotes= function(){
  debugger;
  var quotes = new Array('Stack1','Stack2','Stack16','Stack17','Stack13','Stack14','Stack15','Stack6','Stack7','Stack8','Stack9','Stack10');
  var i;

  for (i=0;i<quotes.length;i++){
    var newquotes = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    document.getElementById('quoteshere').innerText = newquotes;
  }
};
```

```html
<button id="getquotes" value="Quotes" onclick="Loadquotes();">Quotes</button>
<p id="quoteshere" ></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```js
var quotes = Array('Stack1','Stack2','Stack16','Stack17','Stack13','Stack14','Stack15','Stack6','Stack7','Stack8','Stack9','Stack10');
var Loadquotes= function(){
    var newquotes = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    document.getElementById('quoteshere').innerHTML=newquotes;
};
```

```html
<button id="getquotes" value="Quotes" onclick="Loadquotes();">Quotes</button>
<p id="quoteshere" ></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
        <body>
                <button id="getquotes" value="Quotes" onclick="Loadquotes()"> Quotes </button>
                    <p id="quoteshere" ></p>
                        <script>
                function Loadquotes(){
                var quotes = new Array('Stack1','Stack2','Stack16','Stack17','Stack13','Stack14','Stack15','Stack6','Stack7','Stack8','Stack9','Stack10');
                var newquotes = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
                document.getElementById('quoteshere').innerHTML = quotes[newquotes];

                 }
                        </script>
        </body>
```